# convert to a list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have data with this shape

```
  [[array([list([35, 76, 987, 23]),
  list([76, 78, 54, 43]),
  list([2376, 768, 84, 43])],
  dtype=object)]]
```

I want to convert this data to a simple list like this

[35, 76, 987, 23, 76, 78, 54, 43, 2376, 768, 84, 43]

Comment: From the `dtype` argument I conclude, that you are talking about *numpy*. If so, please add that tag.

Answer (score 2):

if your array is inside those 2d list, then you can use this:

```
from numpy import array
from itertools import chain

a = [[array([list([35, 76, 987, 23]),
         list([76, 78, 54, 43]),
         list([2376, 768, 84, 43])],
        dtype=object)]]
flat_list = list(chain(*a))
flat_list = (list(chain(*flat_list)))
flat_list = (list(chain(*flat_list)))

print(flat_list)
```

But I think your `numpy` array is like this:

```
a = array([list([35, 76, 987, 23]),
         list([76, 78, 54, 43]),
         list([2376, 768, 84, 43])],
        dtype=object)
```

then one time using of chain is enough like this:

```
flat_list = list(chain(*a))
    
print(flat_list)
```

Comment: yes, Actually what I wrote was a schematic form of big data which I got from somewhere else and it was an array inside 2 lists (: and your code works, Thank you

Comment: @elham please marked as answer if it helped you so that the question gets resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The cryptic answer:

```
list([[np.array([list([35, 76, 987, 23]),
 list([76, 78, 54, 43]),
  list([2376, 768, 84, 43])],
  dtype=object)]][0][0].flatten())
```

Explanation:

```
from numpy import array
x = [[array([list([35, 76, 987, 23]),
  list([76, 78, 54, 43]),
  list([2376, 768, 84, 43])],
  dtype=object)]]
```

Note that `x` is a numpy array in a list, in a list. You may need to examine your life choices that have led you to arrive at this data structure :-)

Anyway, so `x[0][0]` is the numpy array that you actually want to get your hands on. Numpy arrays have the handy `flatten()` method, so:

```
x[0][0].flatten()
# -> array([35, 76, 987, 23, 76, 78, 54, 43, 2376, 768, 84, 43], dtype=object)
```

Now if you insist on getting a pure python list, just cast it like so:

```
list(x[0][0].flatten())
# -> [35, 76, 987, 23, 76, 78, 54, 43, 2376, 768, 84, 43]
```